# SVD matrix conditioning - how to project from original space to conditioned space?

Tags: svd, projection-matrix, regularized

A classic method of denoising data is to create a matrix, perform SVD, set small singular values to zero, then multiply the decomposed matrix parts to create a new matrix. This is one way of "conditioning" or "regularizing" the input data.

Given a vector in the original matrix space, how do you project that vector into the new conditioned space?

Answer (score 1):

If the decomposition is A ~= Ak = Uk * Sk  * Vk', then you can get an expression for just Uk by multiplying on the right by right-inverses. You want to take off V', and "half" of S, meaning its square root. So we're really working with Ak ~= (Uk * sqrt(Sk)) * (sqrt(Sk) * Vk')

The right-inverse of Vk' is Vk, since it's orthonormal. The inverse of a diagonal matrix is just the diagonal matrix of its reciprocals. Call the inverse of sqrt(S) 1/sqrt(S)

So Uk * sqrt(Sk) = Ak * Vk * 1/sqrt(Sk)

This is how you project a row of Ak. Something entirely similar goes for columns:

sqrt(Sk) * Vk' = 1/sqrt(Sk) * Uk' * Ak